# Installing web browser in Android Wear Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-wear

How can we install a web browser like Chrome / others in an emulator of Android Wear?

Comment: Good luck browsing on a 1.5" screen!

Comment: There is something beyond browsing we would like to test.we really don't mind if you are able to suggest.

Comment: if you need to show something in a browser window, try using a WebView if you are making an app. However, if you are making an app and need help, I'd advise you to go to stack overfloe

Comment: We have already developed a web application using cordova technology , but as cordova is nt supported in android wear , the only way left is to run in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

[Web Browser for Android Wear by appfour](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearbrowser) is the only browser for Android wear at the moment.

Comment: AFAIK, Android emulator from Android SDK doesn't have Play Store installed because of license issue, though this answer is still valid since you can sideload the APK.

Comment: other emulators have them. such as bluestacks. i mean, its not for wear, but my point is that it might not be the SDK emulator hes looking at